# Can I write a conditional AND to test for "ISNUMERIC" and then CAST a string to an int in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I thought (hoped) this would work but it doesn't, it evaluates both sided of the AND statement  even if the left side is going to be false:

```
SELECT PropertyNumber
FROM Properties
WHERE PropertyNumber = '203a'
AND
(                                
NOT PropertyNumber LIKE '[^0-9]' AND CONVERT(INT,PropertyNumber) > 0
)
```

So I get:

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '203a' to data type int.
```

Is there anyway to do conditional AND or any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two steps:

```
SELECT
    OtherField, CAST(PropertyNumber AS INT) AS PropertyNumber
FROM
    (SELECT OtherField, PropertyNumber FROM Properties WHERE ISNUMERIC(PropertyNumber) = 1) AS X
```

This will discard records with non-numeric property numbers.  If you want to keep them...

```
SELECT
    P.OtherField, P.PropertyNumber AS PropertyNumberAsText, CAST(X.PropertyNumber AS INT) AS PropertyNumberAsInt
FROM
    Properties AS P
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT PropertyNumber FROM Properties WHERE ISNUMERIC(PropertyNumber) = 1) AS X ON P.PropertyNumber = X.PropertyNumber
```

Because `ISNUMERIC()` approves of some values which cannot be cast to `INT`, I tend to use something like this:

```
CASE WHEN Field IN ('-', '.') THEN NULL
     WHEN Field LIKE '%,%' THEN NULL
     WHEN ISNUMERIC(Field) = 1 THEN CAST(Field AS INT) END
```

Note that this will reject values like "1,234", which is a valid integer in some regions.  Code to identify and handle all possible formats for numeric values is a separate question, and has probably been asked on SO before.

Comment: `Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '.' to data type int.`

Comment: `SELECT ISNUMERIC('.')` returns 1!
Add `AND PropertyNumber != '.'`?

Comment: `SELECT ISNUMERIC('15, ')` also returns 1?!?!

Comment: Yep, `ISNUMERIC` is pretty flawed.  I'll edit in the logic I prefer.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT PropertyNumber
FROM @Temp
WHERE PropertyNumber = '203a'
AND
(   
case When IsNumeric('-' + PropertyNumber + 'e0') = 1
     Then Convert(Int, PropertyNumber)
     Else NULL
     End > 0
)
```

The trick here is to use the knowledge that IsNumeric will return 1 only under certain conditions.  By putting  a '-' sign in front of your data, you are effectively making sure that property numbers are positive.  By putting 'e0' after the column name, you are preventing floating point values.